# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders, uses HTTP Options method instead of GET and POST from the redirected method

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webrequest

```
//PUT HEADERS IS REDIRECTED REQUEST
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    info =>{
        info.method = "GET"
        //alert('onBeforeSendHeaders redirect ' +info.method);
        let key = info.url.replace(replace, 'key-');
        let currentHeaders =  info.requestHeaders;
        let requestHeaders = map.get(key)
        requestHeaders.push(...currentHeaders);
        requestHeaders.push({'name':'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'value':'*'})
        requestHeaders.push({'name':'ISISessionid', 'value':'null'})
        return {requestHeaders}
    },
    {urls : [`${replace}/*`]},
    ['blocking','requestHeaders','extraHeaders'])
```

In this I am trying to insert some extra headers in a redirected GET request. The headers are added successfully, but the request method changes to 'OPTIONS' every time.

I tried to force the method, but it also does not works.

Comment: Make sure both the original and all redirected URLs are matched by `"permissions"` in your manifest.json. Otherwise it may be a bug in Chrome, report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: See also https://crbug.com/20624#c11